# libXext.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, c

i am trying to compile [FreeRDP](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP) i have this cmake commands

```
cmake -DMONOLITHIC_BUILD=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \

-DWITH_SSE2=OFF -DWITH_ALSA=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=OFF -DWITH_MANPAGES=OFF \

-DWITH_SERVER_INTERFACE=OFF -DWITH-PULSE=OFF -DWITH_GSTREAMER_1_0=OFF \
-DWITH_XKBFILE=OFF -DWITH_XINERAMA=OFF -DWITH_XEXT=OFF -DWITH_XCURSOR=OFF \

-DWITH_XV=OFF -DWITH_XI=OFF -DWITH_XRENDER=OFF -DWITH_XFIXES=OFF .
```

when i launch `make` command i got this error

> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/xfreerdp-client.dir/xf_floatbar.c.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XShapeCombineMask'
> //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> client/X11/CMakeFiles/xfreerdp-client.dir/build.make:497: recipe for target 'client/X11/xfreerdp' failed
> make[2]: *** [client/X11/xfreerdp] Error 1
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3243: recipe for target 'client/X11/CMakeFiles/xfreerdp-client.dir/all' failed
> make[1](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP): *** [client/X11/CMakeFiles/xfreerdp-client.dir/all] Error 2
> Makefile:133: recipe for target 'all' failed
> make: *** [all] Error 2

libraries installed:

> libssl1.0-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev libxinerama-dev libxcursor-dev
> libxdamage-dev libxv-dev libxkbfile-dev libasound2-dev libcups2-dev
> libxml2 libxml2-dev libxrandr-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev
> libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libavutil-dev libavcodec-dev
> libusb-1.0-0-dev libxtst-dev

any fixes or idea how to solve